# Please add pagination option to preferences

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, pagination, preferences

Please add an option to preferences making it possible to set how many pages to show on one screen.

Answer (score 1):

There is a selector for 15, 30, and 50 questions at the bottom of the page of any question list. Thus is "sticky" and saved in your profile. So this already exists..

```
<div class="page-sizer">
<a href="/questions?page=1&amp;sort=newest&amp;pagesize=15" title="show 15 items per page" class="current page-numbers">15</a>
<a href="/questions?page=1&amp;sort=newest&amp;pagesize=30" title="show 30 items per page" class="page-numbers">30</a>
<a href="/questions?page=1&amp;sort=newest&amp;pagesize=50" title="show 50 items per page" class="page-numbers">50</a>
<span class="page-numbers desc">per page</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Smart, too smart I would say. I think that having this setting **also** in user's preferences wouldn't hurt.